# How to form a new tuple with the first value of each tuple of a tuple of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, select, tuples, element

I want to form a tuple with the first elements of each tuple. Im a beginner in python, maybe this is an easy one but i cant find a way to do it plz help.

ex:

input

```
 x = (('A','B','C'),('D','E','F'),('G','H','I'))
```

output:

```
y= ('A', 'D', 'G')
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Should be very straightforward to loop you elements for each and get the first position of each tuple. Have you tried this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use comprehension and convert to a tuple;

```
>>> x = (('A','B','C'),('D','E','F'),('G','H','I'))
>>> y = tuple([l[0] for l in x])
>>> y
('A', 'D', 'G')
```

Comment: Or just `tuple(l[0] for l in x)`, using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks.  I'd tried just `(l[0] for l in x)`, and totally missed the generator aspect of it.

Comment: That syntax was taken by genexps, and any alternative tuple comprehension syntax wouldn't have been more readable than `tuple(... for ... in ...)`.

Comment: @CAB only one question: what does that 'l' stands for?

Comment: @PedroGonçalves  `for l in x` is a loop through all the elements in `x` with `l` taking on the value of each item in turn.  `l` is just  the key I hit, it could as easily been 'k', or 'z', or even an underscore ('_').

Answer (score 3):

```
x = (('A','B','C'),('D','E','F'),('G','H','I'))

for each in zip(*x):
    print(each)
```

prints:

```
('A', 'D', 'G')
('B', 'E', 'H')
('C', 'F', 'I')
```

Use the `zip()` function. [Read more here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Edited:

like CAB says if you just want the first one you can do:

```
y = zip(*x)[0]
```

Comment: If you only want the first tuple;  `y = zip(*x)[0]`